# Code is giving heap buffer overflow error message

Tags: arrays, c, for-loop, function-definition

This is the LeetCode question i'm solving-

Given an integer array nums of length n, you want to create an array ans of length 2n where ans[i] == nums[i] and ans[i + n] == nums[i] for 0 <= i < n (0-indexed).

Specifically, ans is the concatenation of two nums arrays.

Example:

Input: nums = [1,2,1]
Output: [1,2,1,1,2,1]

And this is the code i've written-

```
int* getConcatenation(int* nums, int numsSize, int* returnSize){
    *returnSize = numsSize*2;
    int* ans = malloc(numsSize * 2 * sizeof(int));

    for(int i=0; i<numsSize*2; i++){
        ans[i] = nums[i];
        ans[i + numsSize] = nums[i];
    }

    return ans;
}
```

This is giving **heap-buffer-overflow** error. What is that i'm doing wrong here?
PS: I'm new in programming.
**Screenshot Attached**
[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VeIqf.png)

I tried to reallocate the memory using realloc() but it didn't work.

Comment: How do you find the length of the array? [Given that](https://leetcode.com/problems/concatenation-of-array/) `1 <= n <= 1000` there should not be a heap overflow. Does your code work for the given test cases? Note that on-line challenges are not the right place to learn coding.

Comment: Your loop limit is incorrect.

Comment: `for(int i=0; i<numsSize*2; i++){` `nums` is `numSize` in length.  So that should be `for(int i=0; i<numsSize; i++){`

Comment: also, welcome to SO and welcome to the wide world of programming!  we request that you omit screenshots of text unless there is a visual component of the question (eg graphics).  Instead you can copy/paste the text itself. one of the big differences between a beginner programmer and an adept programer , is that the adept programmer looks for understanding in the text of the program source and reproducible behavior .  So always try to provide a complete, reproducible example (something we can compile and run as-is) and avoid the screenshots.

Comment: @WeatherVane, Length of the array should be passed from calling function. I have been learning coding from last 5 months. Now, i've started solving easy questions on LeetCode. Thankyou for your concern.

Comment: @erik258 , thankyou. I'll keep that in my mind next time.

Answer (score 0):

It is evident that due to the condition in the for loop `i<numsSize*2`

```
for(int i=0; i<numsSize*2; i++){
    ans[i] = nums[i];
    ans[i + numsSize] = nums[i];
}
```

the index expressions `i + numsSize` in  `ans[i + numsSize]` and `i` in `nums[i]` provide accessing memory outside the both arrays that results in undefined behavior.

The function can look enough simple if to use standard C function `memcpy`. For example

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//...

int * getConcatenation( const int *nums, size_t numsSize, size_t *returnSize )
{
    int *ans = malloc( 2 * numsSize * sizeof( int ) );

    if ( ans != NULL )
    {
        memcpy( ans, nums, numsSize * sizeof( int ) );
        memcpy( ans + numsSize, nums, numsSize * sizeof( int ) );
    }

    *returnSize = ans == NULL ? 0 : 2 * numsSize;

    return ans;
}
```

If you want to use a for loop then the function can look the following way

```
int * getConcatenation( const int *nums, size_t numsSize, size_t *returnSize )
{
    int *ans = malloc( 2 * numsSize * sizeof( int ) );

    if ( ans != NULL )
    {
        for ( size_t i = 0; i < numsSize; i++ )
        {
            ans[i] = nums[i];
            ans[i + numsSize] = nums[i];
        }       
    }

    *returnSize = ans == NULL ? 0 : 2 * numsSize;

    return ans;
}
```